# Getting "Could not find or load main class" only after I add dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I get this weird problem When I create new maven project and run the App, it's working as expected.
But, When I add some dependencies in pom.xml, clean the project and run the app again, It says "Error: Could not find or load main class com.kishore.HibernateApp.App".

It's just a Hello world printing main class. Nothing fancy about the app.

My Questions are
1) Does is has to do anything with class path?
2) What might have went wrong when I add new dependencies in my pom.xml
3) Is this problem specific, expected? How to resolve this for ever?

**Dependencies added**
[image]

**Run the app as below**
[image]

**Runtime configurations**
[image]
[image]
**Note:** I've seen several answers similar to this error. But found none which has helped me. So I had to post this question.

Comment: It is related to classpath only. for other answers you need to provide more information.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Could you please let me know what information are you expecting from me to add?

Comment: How do you start your project? What dependency you are adding? What difference it makes at runtime classpath?

Comment: We also need to see the complete stacktrace

Comment: @JigarJoshi
Added.

Comment: Can you also add the run configuration for the same?

Comment: @StephenC Stacktrace I see only one line in console as you can see in the second image.
It just says "Could not find or load main class" error.

Comment: Look in the errors view.

Comment: @StephenC I see no errors in the errors view.

Comment: @StephenC Do you think it is a specific issue? Specific to me?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Added

Comment: click on `main` tab and repost

Comment: @JigarJoshi I've posted main tab as well before. What else you need?

Comment: Nothing looks bad. Can you verify if there is a compiled class present in your `target/classes/com/kishore/HibernateApp/` directory with name `App.class`

Comment: @Jigar Joshi
Resolved!!!
I had to close eclipse, remove all content in the .m2 then restart Eclipse worked me.
What's wrong with the .m2, I still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
maven clean 
maven install
```